# Database design advice in Rails, The Pizza, Topping and Order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, many-to-many

Yes, its another database question with the pizza analogy.
The ones I've seen don't seem to click just right, so here goes.

I need to be able to order multiple pizzas with any number of toppings in a single order.
Its a basic shopping cart pattern, but the toppings are making it difficult to implement.

The base models are,

```
class Pizza < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
  has_and_belongs_to_many :toppings
end

class Topping < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :pizzas  
end
```

Pizza and Topping tables serve as the holder for the information of pizza and topping types that can be ordered.

```
class OrdersPizzas < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :pizza
end

class PizzasToppings < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topping
  belongs_to :pizza
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :pizzas
end
```

**[Added]**

Some clarification, the database design is intended for a shopping app, so being able to setup a "menu" by an admin, and users being able to see the menu, and order from it is imperative.

The operation of this goes in two steps, first you need to make a menu by creating the Pizzas and toppings, and associating them, not all pizzas can have all the toppings.

> A Cheese Pizza can have extra olives, and extra cheese as toppings
>
> A Peperoni Pizza can have only extra cheese for toppings

Step two is actually placing the orders according to the entered data, thus all the many to manys.

Now the question is, after entering the data above, I want to place an order

> Peperoni Pizza with extra cheese
>
> Cheeze Pizza with extra olives

in a single order, how should it be designed?

All I can think of is to add a

```
class OrdersPizzasToppings < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :orders_pizzas
  belongs_to :topping
end
```

so I can distinguish which pizza has the toppings, but that does not look like the right way to go.

Comment: A `Pizza` can't belong to more than 1 `Order`, can it?

Comment: my question was put the wrong way, have clarified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, have came up with a way that works for me, explanations for each model included
above each.

The Pizza model, to create a list of pizzas that can be ordered by customers, also gets associated with order, so to indicate which pizza has been ordered.

```
class Pizza < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :pizza_orders
  has_many :orders, :through => :pizza_orders
  has_and_belongs_to_many :toppings
end
```

Topping model, to create a list of toppings that can be associated with certain pizzas, also gets associated with the join table for each pizza order, to specify which pizza has the topping ordered.

```
class Topping < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :pizzas
  has_and_belongs_to_many :pizza_orders
end
```

The join table for pizza and topping, this is needed because without it, you can not specify which toppings can or can not be ordered with a pizza. After all, having peperoni topping listed to a vegetarian pizza might offend someone.

```
class PizzasToppings < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pizza
  belongs_to :topping
end
```

The order model, this just holds all the join tables together.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pizza_orders
  has_many :pizzas, :through => :item_orders
end
```

The join table between pizza and order, this many to many is a has many through, and not a has and belongs to many since in Rails you cannot directly manipulate HBATM join tables (as far as I have tried), and you need to be able to because of the options relation ship.

```
class PizzaOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pizza
  belongs_to :order

  has_and_belongs_to_many :options
end
```

The join table to indicate which toppings have been chosen for a particular pizza in a order.

```
class PizzaOrdersToppings < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pizza_orders
  belongs_to :topping
end
```

Then having an admin page to create and associate the Pizzas and toppings, and an order page to create orders, this should work. This way its easy to make sales analysis, which toppings is most popular with what pizza, and what not.

Comment: request you please correct the places you have used item_orders, options, toppings and pizzas. Could you make it consistent. Would be great help thanks

Comment: have you managed to create the Create Orders page. I'm struggling could please share this on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641079/how-to-create-nested-form-in-ruby-on-rails/18643327?noredirect=1#18643327

Comment: Sorry about that carbonr, the options model was from the original code, forgot to fix it into toppings, fixed now

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a join table to represent a set of toppings applied to one pizza and also separate out the standard pizza that the toppings are applied to:

```
class Pizza < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :standard_pizza
  has_one :pizza_topping
  has_many :toppings, through: :pizza_topping
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pizzas
end

class Topping < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pizza_toppings
  has_many :pizzas, through: :pizza_toppings
end

# A set of toppings applied to one pizza
class PizzaTopping < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pizza
  belongs_to :topping
end

# Pepperoni pizza, Cheese pizza ...
class StandardPizza < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pizzas
end
```

Comment: That and perhaps having a join table between standard pizza and topping, to set which pizza can have which toppings, it would work. Thanks. I've came up with another approach, adding my version for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll agree with Zabba - a `Pizza` should belong to one `Order`. Now, I think you can apply a simpler solution. From what I've read and if I'm not mistaken, you can use 3 models.

```
class Pizza < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  has_many :toppings
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pizzas
end

class Topping < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pizza  
end
```

Comment: Edited question, forgot to mention that it needed shopping cart capability.

Comment: If you need orders to get info about toppings you can always add `has many :toppings, :through => :pizza` to `Order` and `belongs_to :order to `Topping`

Comment: But wouldn't that endup having a new pizza or topping entry per order? Where would you hold the information(name ingredients, price etc.)of the pizzas and toppings? It'll work if the pizza info is hard coded but being able to add pizzas and toppings is desired.