# How to create nested form in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, simple-form

I have following arragement

The Pizza model, to create a list of pizzas that can be ordered by customers, also gets associated with order, so to indicate which pizza has been ordered.

```
class Pizza < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :pizza_orders
  has_many :orders, :through => :pizza_orders
  has_and_belongs_to_many :toppings
end
```

Option model, to create a list of options that can be associated with certain pizzas, also gets associated with the join table for each pizza order, to specify which pizza has the topping ordered.

```
class Topping < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :pizzas
  has_and_belongs_to_many :pizza_orders
end
```

The join table for pizza and topping, this is needed because without it, you can not specify which toppings can or can not be ordered with a pizza. After all, having peperoni topping listed to a vegetarian pizza might offend someone.

```
class PizzasToppings < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pizza
  belongs_to :topping
end
```

The order model, this just holds all the join tables together.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pizza_orders
  has_many :pizzas, :through => :pizza_orders
end
```

The join table between pizza and order, this many to many is a has many through, and not a has and belongs to many since in Rails you cannot directly manipulate HBATM join tables (as far as I have tried), and you need to be able to because of the options relation ship.

```
class PizzaOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pizza
  belongs_to :order

  has_and_belongs_to_many :toppings
end
```

The join table to indicate which toppings have been chosen for a particular pizza in a order.

```
class PizzaOrdersToppings < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pizza_orders
  belongs_to :topping
end
```

Then I have an admin page to create and associate the Pizzas and toppings.

But I don't know how to create the orders form. The user should be able to add a pizza and select one or many toppings which are already created

Answer (score 2):

Its a bit old screencast [Nested model form part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) made by ryan bates but i hope it helps you , also there is a revised version of this screencast.

Comment: this wouldn't work, ryan is creating new questions and answer. I just want to ADD questions and answers to an order not create.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I was late to respond.

Okay, haven't tested this, but hope it gets you the idea. In order for it to work, this sample relies on,

1. simple_form
2. the ryan bates dynamic nested form

I have  to apologize, this answer is lacking a large part of it, you need to re-render the link_to_add_fields part every time you change the <%= f.association :pizzas %> value so that the hidden field that contains the toppings match the pizza that has been selected.

Sorry I couldn't get you completly through, but  I hope this points you in the right direction.

_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form @order do |f| %>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :pizza_orders do |pizza_orders_fields| %>
    <%= f.association :pizzas %>
    <%= render partial: "pizza_order_fields", locals: {f: pizza_orders_fields}%>
    <%= link_to_add_fields "Add", f, :pizza_orders %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

pizza_order_fields.html.erb would look like

```
<fieldset>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to "Delete", '#', class: "remove_fields btn btn-danger" %>
  <%= f.association toppings_pizza_orders, collection: f.object.pizza.toppings %>
</fieldset>
```